# How to go to next Activity in Android

Tags: android

I have three views main1.xml, main2.xml , main3.xml.  In main.xml I'm putting three buttons. When the user clicks on first button I want it to show main1.xml, if second button then main2.xml etc.. I am done with the main.xml files.

How to do I change the view?

Comment: atleast you have tried to use google first

Comment: Why this much of negatives for a beginner. Somebody should guide him how to ask questions and that will be enough. down voting will discourage him from coming back to stackoverflow. everybody doesn't know everything!!

Comment: nice question but i will give you +1

Comment: Please Read Intent if you are good in Intent so whole android world is open for you...best of luck

Comment: @Shruti : I am sorry I should have look for google.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Its very simple, you just need to use Intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
this.startActivity ( intent );
```

Comment: Check my answer below, which is used to **change view** because his question is "how to do that view change?"

Comment: But his question title is different, and also he has use my code which was helpful to him.

Answer (score 2):

I think this question is not about to go to next activity, but to flip sub-layouts to display on the screen.

I am sure the solution which i am going to suggest you, will suites your requirement exactly.

The solution is to implement [**`ViewFlipper`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) widget in your xml layout. Because  the main purpose of ViewFlipper is to flip Views whenever required.

As you are having three sub-layouts main1.xml, main2.xml , main3.xml in main.xml layout,  you just need include this sub-layouts as:

```
<ViewFlipper>
    <LinearLayout/>        <!-- main1.xml -->
    <LinearLayout/>        <!-- main2.xml -->  
    <LinearLayout/>        <!-- main3.xml -->  
</ViewFlipper>
```

Now, in your Activity, you have to find this ViewFlipper by their id by using `findViewById()` method.

Now, to show a particular layout on the click event of its related button, you have to call **`myViewFlipper.setDisplayedChild()`**.

For example: 
On clicking of 1st button, you just need to write:

```
myViewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(0);
```

**You can refer this example:** [View Flipper Example](http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2012/03/view-flipper-example-android.html)

Answer (score 1):

Call method `setcontentView(r.layout.main1),setcontentView(r.layout.main2),setcontentView(r.layout.main3)` from click event of you three button respectively.

Comment: Thanks dude but this will not allow me  to create my whole new class of acitivity ? am I right ?

Answer (score 1):

Use Intents ,

in your main activity create a button and inside its onClick do this

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent=new  Intent(mainActivity.this,nextActivity.class);
                 startActivity(intent);


                }
            });
```

And in your next Activity's onCreate() , use `setContentView(//ur xml);`

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), QuizSectionActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Please explain why you are suggesting this approach. Especially the use of `getApplicationContext()`, since this is the only difference between your answer and the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

use Intent in startActivity
.

```
startActivity(new Intent(FirstActivity.this, secondActivity.class);
```

Comment: if you could expand as to why your answer works, that will be helpful